# MySQL Server: moving just some database to another location

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb, symlink

I was trying to do the following trick:

- move a particular database directory to another location (different physical drive);
- create a symlink using *ln -s* from mysql data dir to the new location.

It fails when trying to restart *mysql* with the following error:

```
InnoDB: os_file_readdir_next_file() returned -1 in directory ./...
```

It seems that symlinks won't work for this purpose. Is there a way to trick the system?

Comment: Symlinks do work for this purpose. No clue about the error you are getting though.

Comment: @Vatev Will try again then. Maybe it was a mess up with rights.

Comment: I see you tagged your question ubuntu (linux), but what does `select @@version` show for MySQL?

Comment: Using a symlink is fine, but you need to configure apparmor to allow access to the new path (e.g. add it to `etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`), see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/137946) (you have to do this wether you edit the mysql config file to use the new directory, or if you use a symlink).